# jQuery Live function not working

Tags: jquery

I am working on a small project with jQuery, so far so good, but I am having an issue with jQuery's .live() function.

In my source code below you will see:

```
colourMenu.children('li').live('click', selectColour);
```

The list elements are populated to an empty UL element via an ajax request which parses JSON. Can anyone tell me why it wont apply the live function? If it was working it would update a hidden input field by the notion of updateOption();

NOTE: the json request is called after the selectMaterial method has been actioned

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.juniperNotebooks = function() {

        /*
        == Default
        */

        var ajaxFile = 'notebookAPI.php';
        var nopt = $('#notebookSelectedOpts'); 
        var complete = false;   
        var debug = true;

        /*
        == Attributes
        */  

        // Steps
        var actions = {
            size: false,
            material: false,
            colour: false,
            paper: false
        }

        // Extras
        var extras = {
            emboss: false,
            elastic: false,
            pen: false,
            pocket: false
        }

        // Buttons
        var sizeButton = $('.btn.size');
        var materialButton = $('.btn.material');
        var colourButton = $('.btn.matcolour');

        // Menu's
        var sizeMenu = $('.menu.size');
        var materialMenu = $('.menu.mats');
        var colourMenu = $('.menu.colour');

        init();

        /*
        == Plugin Functions 
        */

        function init() {

            // CSS Opacity for all but the first button
            $('.btn').css('opacity', 0.5).first().css('opacity', 1).addClass('req');

            // Attach refresh function to reset link
            $('.refresh').bind('click', resetPage);

            // Attach click to first button: Size
            sizeButton.bind('click', showSizes);

            // Attach click handlers to options:
            sizeMenu.children('li').bind('click', selectSize);
            materialMenu.children('li').bind('click', selectMaterial);
            colourMenu.children('li').live('click', selectColour);

        }

        /*
        == Plugin Functions 
        */

        /*
        == Menu Selector Functions 
        */

        function showSizes() {              
            delegateActiveButtonState(sizeButton);
            toggleMenu(sizeMenu);                           
        }

        function showMaterials() {
            delegateActiveButtonState(materialButton);
            toggleMenu(materialMenu);       
        }

        function showColours() {    
            delegateActiveButtonState(colourButton);    
            toggleMenu(colourMenu);         
        }       

        /*
        == Additional Menu Selector Functions 
        */

        function toggleMenu(menu) {

            if( menu.is(':hidden') ) {
                menu.slideToggle(500);      
            } else {
                menu.slideToggle(500);
            }       

        }

        function hideMenu(menu) {
            return menu.slideToggle(500);
        }

        /*
        == Option Selector Functions
        */      

        function selectSize() {

            var option = $(this).data('size');  
            delegateActiveButtonState(sizeButton);

            if( !checkComplete() ) {

                updateOption('selectedSize', option);   
                debug__(option+' size has been selected.');

                if( option == 'a4' ) {

                    updateOption('selectedPaper', 'lined'); 
                    debug__('Lined paper has been selected by default.');       

                } else { updateOption('selectedPaper', '');  }

                hideMenu(sizeMenu);
                sizeButton.removeClass('req');

                actions.size = true;

                materialButton.unbind('click', showMaterials).bind('click', showMaterials).css('opacity', 1).addClass('req');

            } else {

                // Do stuff after we have already made a notebook

            }           

        }

        function selectMaterial() {

            var option = $(this).data('matid'); 
            delegateActiveButtonState(materialButton);

            if( !checkComplete() ) {

                updateOption('selectedMaterial', option);   
                debug__('Material ID: '+option+' has been selected.');

                hideMenu(materialMenu);
                materialButton.removeClass('req');

                actions.material = true;

                colourButton.unbind('click', showColours).bind('click', showColours).css('opacity', 1).addClass('req');

                colourMenu.empty();
                getAvailableColours( option );

            } else {

                // Do stuff after we have already made a notebook

            }           

        }

        function selectColour() {

            var option = $(this).data('colourid');  
            delegateActiveButtonState(colourButton);

            if( !checkComplete() ) {

                updateOption('selectedColour', option); 
                debug__('Colour ID: '+option+' has been selected.');

                hideMenu(colourMenu);
                colourButton.removeClass('req');

                actions.colour = true;

                // if for paper selection here..
                //colourButton.bind('click', showMaterials).css('opacity', 1).addClass('req');

            } else {

                // Do stuff after we have already made a notebook

            }           

        }               

        /*
        == Global Functions
        */

        function getAvailableColours(materialID) {

            if( colourMenu.children('li').length == 0) {
                $.getJSON('json.php?mid='+materialID, function(data) {
                  var items = [];

                  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    items.push('<li data-colourid="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                  });

                  colourMenu.append(items.join(''));

                });
            }           

        }

        function updateOption(opt, val) {
            return nopt.children('#'+opt).val(val);
        }

        function getOption(opt) {
            return nopt.children('#'+opt).val();
        }

        function resetPage() {
            if( confirm('Are you sure you want to reset this page? All data will be lost.') ) {
                location.reload();
            }
            return false;
        }

        function delegateActiveButtonState(btn) {

            if( !btn.hasClass('active') ) {
               return btn.addClass('active');
            } else { return btn.removeClass('active'); }    

        }

        function checkComplete() {
            if( complete ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function debug__(msg) {
            if(debug) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        }

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I have also tried adding the click function after the JSON request within the getAvailableColours function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.live()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/live/) only works directly on selectors:

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to `.live()`. Rather, the `.live()` method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.

There might be other issues with your code, but that is definitive one. Instead of posting a bunch of code and having us trying to figure out how it works, you should create a  http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Thanks I have now sorted out my issue.

Comment: @Nathan: Was this the only problem? If not, you can add your own answer and describe your solution.

Comment: After colourMenu.append(items.join('')); within the getAvailableColours(); function I added beneath colourMenu.find('li').bind('click', selectColour) and it works perfectly.

I always assumed dynamically inserted DOM elements must have live events attached to them... seems not ! ha

Comment: @Nathan: No, they don't. Whenever an element exists, you can bind event handlers to it. You only use `live` or `delegate` to bind event handlers to elements that don't exist yet. So in general you have two options: Use `live` and "forget" about it, or bind the handlers when you created the element.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it has to do with `checkComplete();` That function is looking at the value of the global var `complete`. If that variable has been set to `true` by another click listener, then your `colourmenu` code will not execute.